# Python / MySQL Select returns None with %s

Tags: python, mysql, beautifulsoup

I'm currently working on learning Python and I'm already stuck on a strange problem.

I'm getting urls from a website using *beautifulsoup*, which I can already save to a mysql database. Now I want to let the script first check if a crawled url is already in the database.

The query looks like this:

```
check_url = "SELECT url FROM shop_ig " \
    "WHERE url = '%s'"
```

Here I'm getting the url:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser")

for link in soup.findAll('a', {'class': 'ig-preorders-item'}):
    href = link.get('href')
    print(href)
```

Now that I have the url I would like to check if href is already in the database so I execute the query using:

```
    ## Check if url is in db
    cursor.execute(check_url, href)
    data = cursor.fetchone()
    sqlconnect.commit()
```

Now to the strange thing, data returns None, however, if I enter an url permanently into the query it finds the url in the database.

Comment: can you print cursor._executed ?

Comment: yes, that returns b"SELECT url FROM shop_instantgaming WHERE url = '%s'"

interesting

Comment: `cursor.execute(check_url, (href, ))` instead of `cursor.execute(check_url, href)`.

Comment: Take out that single quote thats wrapping your %s: `"WHERE url = %s"`

Comment: Try: `check_url = "SELECT url FROM shop_ig WHERE url = '{0}'".format(some_string)`

Comment: thanks for all the help guys, got it fixed :)

Comment: @heinst You are suggesting a solution that is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [alexce](https://stackoverflow.com/users/771848/alecxe) I found the problem.

I'm now using:

```
cursor.execute(check_url, (href, ))
```

The select now looks like this ('' removed)

```
check_url = "SELECT url FROM shop_instantgaming " \
"WHERE url = %s"
```